# add python 3.10 on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, upgrade

I'm just started using ubuntu and tried to upgrade python from 3.8.10 -> 3.10.4 in my venv with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install software-properties-common -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y
sudo apt install python3.10
```

it is installed successfully but when I check the version with:

```
python3 --version
```

it still show:

> python 3.8.10

and my code can only work with python version > 3.10. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you check if you have a `python3.10` command?

Comment: Why not have a separate venv for each version?

Comment: yes it has python3.10 command but i don't know how to activate it. it's still in 3.8.10

Comment: because i don't know how :( im new in ubuntu. i just install what it said

Comment: See my answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/410851/153195

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using the deadsnakes PPA. Every version is installed separately, so you can switch versions on the fly. So to use any version installed from deadsnakes, you have to call it explicitely.

```
$ python3.10 --version
Python 3.10.4
```

Comment: yes so i call: python    3.10 --version     to check the version but how can i activate it?

Comment: You don't have to activate it, you just use it.

Comment: If you want it in a virtual environment, `python3.10 -m venv myenv` will create `myenv` (maybe also install `python3.10-pip` and `python3.10-venv`) which when you `activate` it will let you call this version of Python with just `python`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `update-alternatives`, following such approach https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux

You'll be able to choose more conveniently which python version you want to use.